# Hi everyone i have build a flatlist in which names are there now i want to click on that name to show its details

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

1. I have build a flat list in which customers name are there only names.
2. Now i want to click on that names to show customers details i have details in fire store
   database.
3. Just need your help to solve this.
4. there is a name and email in this screen there a lot more about this detail in database. like contact number, area, time and date etc.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { db } from "../firebase";

function DetailsScreen() {

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  var today = new Date();

  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


  // 'createdDate', '>=', last7DayStart FOR LAST WEEK THIS LOGIC
  // 'createdDate', '>=', lastMonthThisDay FOR LAST MONTH THIS LOGIC

  // var last7DayStart = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'week').format('M/DD/YYYY');
  // var lastMonthThisDay = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'month').format('M/DD/YYYY');
  // var yesterdayEndOfRange = moment().endOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').format('D/MM/YYYY');
  // console.log(last7DayStart);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db.collection("contacts").where('createdDate', '<', today).get();
      setContacts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  function handleUpdate() {
    alert("updated")
  };

  function handleDelete() {
    alert("Successfully Removed")
  };

  return (

    <FlatList
      style={styles.list}
      data={contacts}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={9}>
        <Text style={styles.text1}> Student Details </Text>
        {"\n"}
        {"\n"}
        Name: {item.name}
        {"\n"}
        Email: {item.email}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleUpdate()} style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ borderWidth: 0.80 }}> Update </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleDelete()} style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}>
          <Text style={{ borderWidth: 0.75 }}> Delete </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Text>}
    />
  )
};

export default DetailsScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    paddingLeft: 15,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingBottom:10
  },
  list: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  text1: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingTop:5
  }
});
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you have done already, and include clear details about any issues. We can't help fix code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese please have a look at it what should i do.  Do i have to use the touchableOpacity if i use it then how to see the all details. props or something like that.

Comment: I would abstract the `renderItem` logic into a React component with a toggle state that conditionally renders the additional detail values.

Comment: i have no idea what you are telling can you please share the code that would be very much beneficial for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would abstract the `renderItem` logic into a React component with a toggle state that conditionally renders the additional details values. This allows for each rendered flatlist element to maintain its own state to conditionally show or hide the additional details.

```
const ContactDetail = ({ contact, handleUpdate, handleDelete }) => {
  const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDetail = () => setShowDetail(show => !show);

  return (
    <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={9}>
      <Text style={styles.text1}> Student Details </Text>
      {"\n"}
      {"\n"}
      Name: {contact.name}
      {"\n"}
      Email: {contact.email}

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={toggleDetail} style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ borderWidth: 0.80 }}>Toggle Detail</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleUpdate} style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ borderWidth: 0.80 }}>Update</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleDelete} style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ borderWidth: 0.75 }}>Delete</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {showDetail && (
        <Text>
          {/* show additional contact detail values */}
        </Text>
      )}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

The flatlist

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.list}
  data={contacts}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ContactDetail
      contact={item}
      { ...{ handleUpdate, handleDelete } }
   />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: @kazimali Did you forget to return something either in the new component or in the `renderItem` callback?

Comment: Error: NewDetailScreen(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: no no i wrote the same code as you send and it gives me that error. should i send you the code how i wrote after altering your code into it?

Comment: @kazimali Think you could stand up a small demo of your code in an [Expo snack](https://expo.dev/) including some mocked `contacts` data to render, for us to take a look at?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@kazimbhai/contact-details-project

Comment: @kazimali You had declared `ContactDetail` inside the `App` component and were trying to recursively render itself, this is why nothing was returned to be rendered. I moved `ContactDetail` outside `App` and render it in the flatlist. Check https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/hi-everyone-i-have-build-a-flatlist-in-which-names-are-there-now-i-want-to-click

Comment: thank you so much brother for helping me out. since when i post this question i am in this logic only well i am new to react native thanks again brother. Drew Reese